# Jenkins slave not able to find svn

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a job failing on a slave that builds OK on the master.  SVN is installed in the same location on the master as on the slave `/usr/local/bin/svn`. I have a Jenkins user on the slave and it can run `svn --version` OK.

`[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/jenkins/workspace/projecta && svn --non-interactive update /var/jenkins/workspace/projecta`

```
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] /bin/sh: svn: not found
```

I'm using the Subversion plugin and this works fine on the slave and runs at the start of the job. The problem seems to be that some of the modules use the maven build number plugin.

As you can see in the log above this is running a script which seems to be running as the Jenkins user on the slave and picking up the client on the host which is a different version.

So, I think it is checking out the code with the Subversion plugin version and then trying to up date with the older version on the host's PATH.  It all works fine on the master as this only has one version of svn.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete log as well as config.xml for the job?

Comment: What if you run `/bin/sh -c svn --non-interactive update /var/jenkins/workspace/projecta` from the prompt as Jenkins user?

Comment: Another pointer: write a job containing shell build step that executes _env_, tie it to the slave, and examine the output, especially PATH.

Comment: Ah ha, you may be on to something malenkiy, I ran it as jenkins user and it worked real horrowshow, i got this message. `svn: This client is too old to work with working copy please get a newer Subversion client`.  the version on the slave is different from the one on the master.  i'll get it change and try it again

Comment: If you are using Subvesion Plugin I'd advise against using SVN 1.7 client: the plugin uses SVNKit that does not know how to handle 1.7 format as of yet; use 1.6 client instead.

Answer (score 7):

**Note**: Jenkins Shell runs as /bin/sh, not as bash, and so a lot of the paths you expect to be readily available in bash are actually not there. Even if you run `svn --version` as the jenkins user successfully, chances are you are using bash (and therefore it has loaded certain normal paths into your PATH variable).

**OPTION 1**

Add the following to your "Execute Shell" or shell script:

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

That should let it find subversion. However, you have to do this for every job.

**OPTION 2 - better option**

Another option for you is to add the following on your slave configuration page:

> Configure
>
> Environment Variables
>
> name = PATH
> value = $PATH:/usr/local/bin

This should set it automatically for every build you run on this slave. You can other paths here as you see fit.

Again, note that when you go "System Information" on the slave page, this will not show up (it shows you default Sys Info). However, it will get added for every build

Comment: I had thought using the subversion plugin meant I would not need to do this, but i now know it depends on what plugins you are running

Comment: Yep :) glad to be of help. I think plugin just helps utilise what's already on your system. Just needs a little push in the right direction haha.

Comment: @Sagar Its work for me..How can we access user credentials which we given to jenkins job, via shell script?

Comment: @damithH in the "execute shell" script, just use the "id" command. It should printout the current user and group that the script is running as