# Jenkins - bash command svn can not found

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, svn

I would like to check out tags from svn via Jenkins with bash command. But I get the error message svn command cannot be found, although I have written it clearly.

Here is what my line looks like:

```
svn checkout http://xxx-yyyyy.zzz.xx-www.com:8888/xxx/yyy/$QQQ_tag $DDD/aaa/ --username svc.xxxxx --password
```

Comment: Are you sure svn is installed on the executor?

Comment: And is it in `PATH`?

Comment: Now, Jenkins can find the bash command svn. Yeah I think the svn is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Install the subversion package and retry. On linux:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

On mac with Homebrew:

```
brew install subversion
```

When you've installed it, if bash still cannot find it, check out that you have added the svn executable path to your PATH environment variable and reopen the terminal.

Check out this answer for more details on setting PATH for Jenkins
[Jenkins slave not able to find svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853257/jenkins-slave-not-able-to-find-svn)